# Не понимаю , как передать данные из активити во фрагмент

Tags: android, kotlin, list, serializable

Я только начинаю работать с андроид , поэтому прошу не ругать.Я передаю ArrayList из активити во фрагмент, но не понимаю как его там получить и присвоить куда-то

это я так пытаюсь передать

```html
val dataList=myDbManager.ReadDb()
val bundle=Bundle()
        bundle.putSerializable("1",dataList)
        offline_avtonomnoe.getNewInstance(bundle)
```

А вот так пытаюсь принять

```html
companion object{
    fun getNewInstance(args:Bundle):offline_avtonomnoe{
        val offlineFragment=offline_avtonomnoe()
        offlineFragment.arguments=args
        return offlineFragment
    }


}
```

Иду ли я в правильном направлении? и как это все записать во фрагменте в нормальный ListArray ,а не в аргументы какие-то

Comment: Ps дата лист объявлен от кастомной модельки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите например в вашей activity метод getList() возвращающий ваш list. Потом из фрагмента можете забрать его getActivity.getList();
Или сохраните в статическую переменную ваш list в activity и получите ее из фрагмента getActivity.list;
Или в activity :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle;
bundle.putSerializable ("list", yourList);
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment;
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Позже когда откроете Ваш fragment в нем:

```
getArguments.getSerializable("list");
```

Пишу на jave а там разберетесь =)

Comment: вроде получилось, спасибо

Comment: а нет, не получилось :(

Answer (score 1):

Это не очень хороший подход. Обычная практика передавать из активности во фрагмент идентификатор какой-то определенной строки в базе к примеру. Но передавать через аргументы весь список это оверхед. Намного удобнее и логичнее запросить этот список в самом фрагменте. То есть данные между различными экранами обычно передают через модель.